# how to set both select boxes to the same option value as default

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 select boxes in the same fieldset. I am adding an option to both using jquery and I want them both to have the same default value.

```
$(function(){
    var selectbox = $('.selectbox select');
    selectbox.prepend('<option value="Select a question" selected="selected">Select a question</option>');
    selectbox.children('option').each(function() {
        var option = $(this);
        option.removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

I even try to remove the disabled attribute that it sets and I can't seem to figure out why its setting the second selectbox as disabled for the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `prepend` the option to each `select` using `.each()` loop like below:

```
var selectbox = $('.selectbox select');
selectbox.each(function() {
    $(this).prepend('<option value="Select a question" selected="selected">Select a question</option>');
});
```

Your code add `option` to one `select`. And you don't need to `disable` them for `prepend` purpose.

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/643/)***

#### Note

If your `option` has `disabled` attribute, I think this should not make any problem with above code. **[SEE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/644/)**.

And to remove `disabled` attribute from all `option` you can do:

```
var selectbox = $('.selectbox select');
selectbox.each(function() {
    $(this).find('option').removeAttr('disabled'); // remove disabled attr
    $(this).prepend('<option value="Select a question" selected="selected">Select a question</option>');
});
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/646/)***

Comment: I tried that but it still sets the second one to be disabled.

Comment: I can't post the html its a grails app. Is disabled a default or maybe its getting set somewhere les in the app.

Comment: @user1096509 ok, but I think disabled has no conflict with above code and provide you the demo

Comment: Yes I can see that which leads me to believe its getting set to disabled in some other js file.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by finding select menus, then prepend option element, then finding the first option and setting it selected:

```
$('.selectbox select')
  .prepend('<option value="Select a question" selected="selected">Select a question</option>')
  .find('option:first-child').attr('selected', 'selected');​
```